# Recursive function of Bezier Curve python

Tags: python, recursion, bezier

I am asked to design a recursive function called Bezier which parametres are a list of points given, and the point that must be evaluated t. It returns the point in the Bezier curve defined by the control points of the list of points.

This is the algorithm that I have done:

```
def Bezier(point_list, t):
    if len(point_list)==1:
        return point_list[0]
    else:
        P1=Bezier(point_list[0:-1],t)
        P2=Bezier(point_list[1:],t)
        P=(1-t)*P1 + t*P2
        return P
```

and this is the list of points given:

```
point_list=[ (0,0), (10,-1), (13,5), (-7,8), (2,2) ]
```

How can I know if my function is correct?

Comment: How about, graph the results and see if they look good?

Comment: I'm don't understand why you are making recursive calls on Bezier; it looks like the degree of the curve varies depending on the number of points passed? That is very strange.

Comment: That's typical of Bezier curves, @HughBothwell. A curve of order N has exactly N+1 control points.

Comment: @Kevin: ... yes, but usually you choose a fixed order Bezier (ie cubic) and do piecewise interpolation across the list of points (ie, 4 points at a time)

Comment: I don't really get what you mean, but the OP seems to be basing his code on this [recursive formula given by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Recursive_definition)

Comment: @Kevin: you are correct; I am used to seeing a four-point analytic solution for cubic bezier rather than the recursive definition.

Comment: Your implementation is correct. You are implementing a linear bezier. Depending of the value you chose for `t`, you will get the exactly control points value.

Comment: One check would be to see if the point returned lies on the curve defined by list of points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks correct; you could try it on some sets of points and see if the behavior matches what you expect (ie for control points along x=0, y=0, or x=y, all resulting points should lay along the same line).

You can also take advantage of mirroring; ie for all t, `Bezier([a, b, c], t) == Bezier([c, b, a], 1.-t)`. If your results do not show this behavior then your function cannot be correct.

If I try to run the code, I get a TypeError for trying to multiply a tuple by a float; you may need to expand that code, ie

```
def Bezier(point_list, t):
    if len(point_list)==1:
        return point_list[0]
    else:
        P1=Bezier(point_list[0:-1], t)
        P2=Bezier(point_list[1:], t)
        nt = 1. - t
        return (nt * P1[0] + t * P2[0], nt * P1[1] + t * P2[1])
```